# Google Elevation without maps to display

Tags: javascript, service, elevation

i have a req to get the elevation profile for given lat , long. I used below code. However this code is giving the wrong output. I have compared this with google maps result online.

```
function elevationVal(event) 
       {
         var lat = xval passed ;
         var lng = yval passed ;


        var altitudes = [];
        var locations = [];
        var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        locations.push(latlng1);
         var positionalRequest = {
            'locations': locations
         }
         elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
         elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
         var seaLvl  = results[0].elevation;
         eval01.setValue(seaLvl);
         if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

          // Retrieve the first result
          if (results[0]) {
            var seaLvl = altitudes.push(results[0].elevation.toFixed(3));
             var eleval= results[0].elevation;
          } 
          else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Elevation SERVICE FAILED due to: " + status);
        }
      });
}
```

Either of the seaLvl or eleval doesnt give correct elevation value. If some one has developed code without maps pl help me.

Thanks,
RB

Answer (score 1):

I made a jsfiddle to try and it works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/0sgoqqco/

The result is good as in the Google Demo : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService(),
            denali = new google.maps.LatLng($('[name=lat]').val(), $('[name=lng]').val()),
            positionalRequest = {'locations':[denali]};

        elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('#result').text(results[0].elevation);
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Elevation service failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I didn't make a map

Maybe I didn't get the problem

Comment: Thank You for your efforts. i could run in javascript, but when i use the script in application code , it doesnt work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Can you be more specific or give an example ? Thanks